# Wrong "schema" for "AsmXml"

Tags: xml, assembly, xml-parsing

I have a question according to asmxml.
I try to write a schema to a xml file. The schema looks like following:

```
<schema>
        <document name="XRF">
                <collection name="IL">
                        <attribute name="k"/>
                        <collection name="I">
                                <attribute name="k"/>
                                <collection name="M">
                                        <attribute name="k"/>
                                        <attribute name="v"/>
                                </collection>
                                <collection name="P">
                                        <attribute name="k"/>
                                        <attribute name="v"/>
                                        <attribute name="t"/>
                                        <attribute name="d"/>
                                </collection>
                        </collection>
                </collection>
        </document>
</schema>
```

Here the snippet from The XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!--<!DOCTYPE XRF SYSTEM "/apid/xml/xrf.dtd">-->
<XRF r="8.5.2" c="iD2" g="" u="DE23580-apiinlife03" k="918887283" d="20120523" t="235602">
<IL k="1">              
<I k="1007667,361,402"> 
<M k="3" v="GB0008762899"/>     
<M k="187" v="BG Group" l="4"/> 
<P k="33,3,2" v="13.065" t="181502" d="20120522" y="524" n="0" b="779"/>
<P k="2,1,1" v="12.56" t="080025" d="20120523" z="74876" y="272" n="459" b="908"/>
<P k="41,1,1" s="5"/>           
<P k="9,3,2" v="12.73" t="163519" d="20120522" z="8322" y="158" n="0" b="779"/>                  
</I>
</IL>
</XRF>
```

Could someone help me to fix the "schema"? I don't know what am I doing wrong.
Thank you in advance.

Greetings
z.

Comment: One of the wonderful things about XML is you can make the element names anything you want making the data self documenting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Old question, but perhaps it could help some new users landing here.
While defining a schema with AsmXML, you cannot imbricate directly collections like that.

You would rather link a reference to the appropriate definition of the collection you want to use by defining the collection outside the `<document>` section. For example, the correct schema in your case would be :

```
<schema>
    <collection name="M">
        <attribute name="k"/>
        <attribute name="v"/>
    </collection>

    <collection name="P">
        <attribute name="k"/>
        <attribute name="v"/>
        <attribute name="t"/>
        <attribute name="d"/>
    </collection>

    <collection name="I">
        <attribute name="k"/>
        <reference name="M"/>
        <reference name="P"/>
    </collection>

    <document name="XRF">
            <collection name="IL">
                    <attribute name="k"/>
                    <reference name="I" />
            </collection>
    </document>
</schema>
```

Also, be sure to include all the attributes needed in your collection, you can also use groups to do this.
More can be found there : http://tibleiz.net/asm-xml/documentation.html

Hope this helps !

Comment: 'imbricate', whazzat? Also, it's never too late to provide answers, the older a question the more chance people will appreciate it when it is finally answered.

Comment: +1 for imbricate :) @MartijnPieters: My guess is Matthieu means the `<collection>` nodes should not overlap.

Comment: @unutbu: Yay, not sure why I didn't think to pick up the dictionary there. It's been a while, but I learned a new word today! :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Same here. :)

Comment: Haha, don't hesitate to contact me for more semantics lessons :p